# Magento 2.2.5, Is possible to restrict place order based on the customer group?

Tags: magento-2.2.5, customer-group, place-order, website-restriction

In **Magento 2.2.5**, I need to **restrict place order** for some customers who assigned to **certain group**. Is any possibility to restrict place order based on the customer group?

Comment: so is guest user placed an order without login? or do you need to place an order for registered user only ?

Comment: @AasimGoriya Guest order disabled. Only Registered user with particular user group.

Comment: please check my ans, and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Payment Restrictions](https://amasty.com/payment-restrictions-for-magento-2.html)  which restricts and doesn't allow any payment method for customer group which you want to block.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way, when place order in review page there has checking customer group. Customer groups come from settings or you can hard code the group id.

**app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="disable-place-order" type="SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin\PaymentInformationManagement"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="disable-guest-place-order" type="SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin\GuestPaymentInformationManagement"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/Model/Config.php**

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoStackExchange\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

class Config
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $cartRepository;

    /**
     * Config constructor.
     *
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
    }

    public function isAllowPlaceOrder($cartId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->cartRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $customer = $quote->getCustomer();
        // group ID come from settings or set 1 or 2 or 3 that you want
        $restrictGroup = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('magento_stack_exchange\general\restrict_group');
        if ($restrictGroup == $customer->getGroupId()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/Plugin/PaymentInformationManagement.php**

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Api\PaymentInformationManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use SR\MagentoStackExchange\Model\Config;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;

/**
 * Class PaymentInformationManagement
 */
class PaymentInformationManagement
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * PaymentInformationManagement constructor.
     *
     * @param Config $config
     */
    public function __construct(Config $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * Disable order submitting
     *
     * @param PaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject
     * @param int $cartId
     * @param PaymentInterface $paymentMethod
     * @param AddressInterface|null $billingAddress
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
        PaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
        $cartId,
        PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    ) {
        if ($this->config->isAllowPlaceOrder($cartId)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__("The order can't be submitted."));
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/Plugin/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php**

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoStackExchange\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Api\GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;
use SR\MagentoStackExchange\Model\Config;

/**
 * Class GuestPaymentInformationManagement
 */
class GuestPaymentInformationManagement
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * PaymentInformationManagement constructor.
     *
     * @param Config $config
     */
    public function __construct(Config $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    /**
     * Disable order submitting
     *
     * @param GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject
     * @param string $cartId
     * @param string $email
     * @param PaymentInterface $paymentMethod
     * @param AddressInterface|null $billingAddress
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
        GuestPaymentInformationManagementInterface $subject,
        $cartId,
        $email,
        PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    ) {
        if ($this->config->isAllowPlaceOrder($cartId)) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__("The order can't be submitted."));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bhai,Can you please help me with this ? 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260148/magento-2-create-file-type-customer-attribute 

Can't find anything related to it on internet. :(

Comment: This looks like it'd be perfect, and I even included module.xml and and registration.php so I can load it as a custom module, however it doesn't seem to be triggering on the chosen customer group ($restrictGroup = 4;) ... any ideas?? Thanks!