# Magento 2 : Create file type customer attribute

Tags: customer-attribute, magento2.3

I've created customer attribute with type 'file'. Below is my code.

```
$attributesInfo = [
        'upload_documents' => [
            'label' => 'Upload Document',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'input' => 'file',
            'position' => 1000,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]
    ];
```

Attribute created and it works but can't allow me to upload **PDF** file. When I upload it it uploaded with out any error.

Like ,

[image]

After save it returns error like,
[image]

In error log returns nothing.

Is there anything missing ?? Please help.

Comment: Did you try using backend_model?

Comment: @vivek Did you able to create customer file type attribute ?

Comment: Yes I did that. But it will only work with Magento 2.3.1

Comment: @Vivek ok but can we try to without upgrade

Comment: Yes we can do it. I'll post answer with in few hours.